Django queryset filter on a ManyToMany with custom fields
I have the following Django models Block and CustomCondition that are related to each other through a custom ManyToMany relationship which has customs fields and a custom DB table:
from django.db import models


class CustomCondition(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("custom condition name")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "custom_conditions"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class BlockCondition(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(
        "Block",
        related_name="block_condition_as_block",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    custom_condition = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomCondition,
        related_name="block_condition_as_custom_condition",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    choice = models.CharField(
        "choice",
        choices=[
            ("NO_CONDITION", "No condition"),
            ("ACTIVATED", "Activated"),
            ("NOT_ACTIVATED", "Not activated"),
        ],
        default="NO_CONDITION",
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "block_conditions"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.custom_condition.name


class Block(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", null=False)
    block_conditions = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomCondition,
        through="BlockCondition",
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        related_name="blocks_as_block_condition",
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "blocks"

Now I want to filter blocks for each condition name when that condition name is activated:
for c in CustomCondition.objects.all():
    if c.name:
        filtered_blocks = Block.objects.filter(
            block_conditions__custom_condition__name=c.name
        )
        filtered_blocks = filtered_blocks.filter(
            block_conditions__choice__in=["ACTIVATED", "NO_CONDITION"]
        )
        print(filtered_blocks)

But I get the following Django error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'custom_condition' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.
What am I doing wrong here?

I finally figured it out, so posting the answer here if that can be of some help to someone. There were two mistakes:

When filtering based on the ManyToMany related objects, one must not use the through model (here block_conditions) to write the relation in the query filter, but directly use the related object instead (here custom_conditions)

When one has to use a filter condition based on the fields of the through objects, the filter syntax  must use the name of the through model (here blockcondition as the name of the model in lowercase) and not the name of the related field (here block_conditions)


So all in all it would be:
for c in CustomCondition.objects.all():
    if c.name:
        filtered_blocks = Block.objects.filter(
            custom_conditions__name=c.name
        )
        filtered_blocks = filtered_blocks.filter(
            blockcondition__choice__in=["ACTIVATED", "NO_CONDITION"]
        )
        print(filtered_blocks)

